# How to change chrome share link to options

Tags: google-chrome

Recent version of Google Chrome includes a share link option in the address bar. I think that is useful. However, I cannot find how to change the links. I use none of the options listed, but I would love to able to use this to email links quickly. Is there a way to add more of these options? I have included the image of this option down below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to augment the Chrome functionality for that with an addon.

One such is
[Share link via email](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/share-link-via-email/ejdbkikfbnnhmachnnomjfgjbgkcnjkb?hl=en-GB):

> Adds a button and context menu item to send the page URL or a link URL
> via email
>
> Create a new email with the current address, selected link or selected
> text.
>
> The email will include the page title. You can set text to be added
> before and after the page URL in the email.
>
> Email Clients to choose from: Default mail application, Gmail, AOL
> mail, Outlook/Office 365 and Yahoo Mail.

[image]

Comment: I already have an extension similar to this, but if that part could be changed it would be better than having an extension.

Comment: We are not Google here and cannot change its behavior. To ask for an improvement you should submit a feature request to the Chrome developers, and continue using the addon while waiting (perhaps forever).

Comment: I was wondering if that was supported. It is strange that google placed these few companies there giving no option to modify the list. It might be a different way of advertising.

Comment: The Chrome developers don't give access to modify their context menus, perhaps as a matter of policy.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://techdows.com/2021/07/chrome-to-let-you-quickly-share-links-to-social-sites.html), you can get an option to send an email with the windows Mail app. To do so, you have to open this app and log in.

They also claim that you may be able to add some other social network options by running corresponding apps and restarting Chrome. My set of options is different than yours, and they include some sites and apps I've used.

If you need just one email option and don't want to use extentions, you might [repurpose home button to send page to email](https://gtechwi.com/add-send-link-by-email-button-to-google-chrome/).

I also would like to manage this options manually, but there is not much info about it. There is probably a predefined list of available option, and Chrome must be just checking which of them you've used and adds those.